# SwiftUI Core Data Cannot Delete Multiple Rows from List

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app with full SwiftUI flow with Core Data persistence. It is a basic
master/detail style and it solidly works as expected. I want to add a feature to allow
multiple rows to be selected and deleted. Single row swipe to delete works as expected.

I had inspiration from this SO: 58910010 however, that example used an array of
struct items and I have not been able to duplicate the procedure with Core Data objects.

Basically, the functionality of presenting edit check boxes and the button toggling
functions work as expected, but when I tap the Trash icon, the app crashes. There is
no information in the console and nothing of help to me in the thread log.

See Note 1 below in deleteCards(). If I comment out the viewContext save, the app does
not crash and the selected cards are removed from the list but on restart, the cards
still exist. If I leave the viewContext save in place, the app crashes, but on
restart I see that the selected items no longer exist.

Here's a simplified version:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Card.lastName, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var cards: FetchedResults<Card>
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    @State var selection = Set<UUID>()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(cards) { card in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("\(card.wrappedFirstName) \(card.wrappedLastName)")
                        Text("\(card.wrappedComment)")
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: editButton,
                trailing:
                    HStack {
                        addDelButton
                        addExamplesButton
                    }
            )
            .environment(\.editMode, self.$editMode)
            .navigationTitle("Cards")
        }//nav
    }//body

    private var editButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.editMode.toggle()
            self.selection = Set<UUID>()
        }) {
            Text(self.editMode.title)
        }
    }//edit button

    private var addDelButton: some View {
        if editMode == .inactive {
            return Button(action: addCard) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        } else {
            return Button(action: deleteCards) {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
            }
        }
    }//add del button

    private var addExamplesButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.addExampleRecords()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
        }
    }//add examples

    private func deleteCards() {
        for id in selection {
            if let index = cards.lastIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                viewContext.delete(cards[index])
            }
        }
        selection = Set<UUID>()
    
        //Note 1: this crashed the app - but deletions happen
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }//delete Cards

    private func addCard() {
        withAnimation {
            let newCard = Card(context: viewContext)
            newCard.id = UUID()
            newCard.firstName = "NewFirstName"
            newCard.lastName = "NewLastName"
            newCard.creationDate = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }//add card

    private func addExampleRecords() {
    
        let context = self.viewContext
        for c in 0..<10 {
            let nmo = Card(context: context)
            nmo.id = UUID()
            nmo.lastName = "ExLast \(c)"
            nmo.firstName = "ExFirst \(c)"
            nmo.comment = "ExComment \(c)"
            nmo.creationDate = Date()
        }
    }//add example records

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { cards[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }//delete items
}//struct

extension EditMode {
    var title: String {
        self == .active ? "Done" : "Edit"
    }
    mutating func toggle() {
        self = self == .active ? .inactive : .active
    }
}// ext
```

And for completeness:

```
extension Card {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Card> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Card>(entityName: "Card")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged public var comment: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged public var creationDate: Date?

    public var wrappedFirstName: String {
        firstName ?? "no first name"
    }

    public var wrappedLastName: String {
        lastName ?? "no last name"
    }

    public var wrappedComment: String {
        comment ?? "no comment"
    }

    public var wrappedCreationDate: Date {
        creationDate ?? Date()
    }

}

extension Card : Identifiable {

}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 12.3 iOS 14.2

Comment: I remember I already saw reported something like this and could not reproduce crash with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1, so this is a new version defect.

Comment: You reminded me of an issue I found in another app. When you have Core Data manually create the property files it will mark optionals (Core Data type, not Swift) and if you change that sometimes it breaks the process. Note above that I had removed the ? from the UUID. Correcting that, the app no longer crashes - but the selected items are not deleted. On first glance, it looks like selecting a row does not add that object to the selection set. Any thoughts?